# Can i restore a Azure VM to a different resourcegroup?

Tags: azure

I have a VM in Azure in location Central US . I have some restore points (fullbackups).
Can i restore the VM to a different resourcegroup in West US and reconnect to it with RDP ?

this is for disaster recovery if there is an issue with the Azure location or VM .
Also how can we guarantee that any  location wont have issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

You want to restore a VM hosted on the Central US to the West US.

Let's look into the Public Docs.

> You could use the **[Cross Region (secondary region) restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#cross-region-restore)** to
> restore Azure VMs in the secondary region, which is an **[Azure
> paired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions#what-are-paired-regions)** region.
>
> You can restore all the Azure VMs for the selected recovery point if
> the backup is done in the secondary region.
>
> During the backup, snapshots aren't replicated to the secondary
> region. Only the data stored in the vault is replicated. So secondary
> region restores are only vault tier restores. The restore time for the
> secondary region will be almost the same as the vault tier restore
> time for the primary region.
>
> This feature is available for the options below:
>
> - Create a VM
> - Restore Disks

Unfortunately, I don't see the Central US region pairs with the West US region. So for your question if you [can select your specific regional pair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions#can-i-select-my-regional-pairs), answer is no.

[image]

> Some Azure services rely upon regional pairs, such as Azure's
> redundant storage. These services don't allow you to create new
> regional pairings. Similarly, because Azure controls planned
> maintenance and recovery prioritization for regional pairs, you can't
> define your own regional pairs to take advantage of these services.
> However, you can create your own disaster recovery solution by
> building services in any number of regions and leveraging Azure
> services to pair them.

I hope above helped to answer your questions.